# Show Can I pull Each Of These Out Of An Array?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I am having trouble pulling elements out of this multi-dimensional array?

Here is my code below:

```
$ShowTables = $Con->prepare("SHOW TABLES");
$ShowTables->execute();
$ShowTResults = $ShowTables->fetchAll();
```

If I `print_r($ShowTResults);` I get this multi-dimensional array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [Tables_in_alltables] => userinformation [0] => userinformation )
    [1] => Array ( [Tables_in_alltables] => users           [0] => users ) 
)
```

Foreach new table is loaded it adds another dimension of the array. I want to pull each of the table names, out of the multi-dimensional array into a new array which I can use for future plans.

Would anyone have any ideas?

I have tried 1 `foreach` Loop; but this served no justice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to fetch all results of the first column in form of an array:

```
$ShowTResults = $Con->query("SHOW TABLES")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
print_r($ShowTResults);
```

This gives you:

```
Array (
    [0] => userinformation
    [1] => users
)
```

Which I think is what you're looking for.

Another variant (a bit more complicated, but fitting for similar but little different cases) is to fetch the results as function (`PDO::FETCH_FUNC`) and directly map the result:

```
$ShowTResults = $ShowTables->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, function($table) {
    return $table;
});
```

Comment: I don't understaand the structure of this query/line -- Could you explain the usage and how to `print` the results?

Comment: printing the results: `print_r($ShowTResults);`

Comment: Also with that SQL query, you don't need to `prepare()` (you execute it only once, there are no further variables involved), so you can just `query` right ahead. See the edited answer.

Comment: I thought preparing protects from possible injection?

Comment: @user1902584: Yes it does. But because you don't have any variables involved with the query, there is no injection possible. Keep note that I just edited the answer, because there is an easier method. I put it on top now. That is more fitting in your case, the function mapping is for more complicated cases.

Answer (score 0):

A Solution I tried: Perhaps not as other will do, which is in full respect. But Here is mine:

```
$DatabaseTables = array();
foreach($ShowTResults AS $ShowTResult)
{
   foreach ($ShowTResult AS $ShowT)
 {
   $DatabaseTables[] = $ShowT;
 }
}
$DatabaseTables = array_unique($DatabaseTables); //Deletes Duplicates in Array
unset($ShowTResult);
unset($ShowT); // Free up these variables
print_r($DatabaseTables);
```